# How do I return an image using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot. I am designing a system using Spring boot, it's a Restful API. I want to display images that the user has uploaded. I am storing the files in a subfolder "fotos/x" inside resources. I instinctively tried to access it by typing

```
  http://localhost:8080/fotos/76/miniaturas/casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg
```

Holping that Tomcat would serve the image for me but it didn't.

So I went on and tried to build an endpoint, I've encountered an snippet

```
       @GetMapping(value = "/image")
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage() throws IOException {

    InputStream in = null;
    try{
    in = getClass()
      .getResourceAsStream("/fotos/76/miniaturas/casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg");
    }catch(Exception ex){

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);  //toByteArray doesn't exist.
}


}
```

Comment: Seems the question is incomplete/absent. Do you want to serve images per rest and can't?

Comment: You cannot upload files to the classpath. Eventually `src/main/resources` will be part of your jar/war and you cannot uplaod files into the archive. That being said just inject a `ResourceLoader` and return `resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/fotos/76/miniaturas/casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg");` Spring will do the conversion.

Comment: My two cents storing uploaded files in resource folder is not right approach. It has to be stored in folders independent of your source path or build path

Comment: About  the resources folder not being a good place to store the files, I am just searching for a quick solution. I have just a few months working with Spring and Java itselft. When I have more knowledge I will do things more professionally. I will read this question and the comments. Thank you for poiting out though, it's really important.

Answer (score 0):

I found some code that helped me.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/imagens/{dir}/{img}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage(@PathVariable String dir, @PathVariable String img) throws IOException {


     byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/var/www/back_imoveis/back_imoveis/imoveis/src/main/resources/public/fotos/" + dir + "/miniaturas/" + img));

     return bytes;


}
```